# Animation can't be executed a second time

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have an animation that triggers when I click on it. Problem is that I can't trigger it a second time after the first execution. The delay in Javascript seems not working, whatever value you put, the animation stays the same. Normally all this code is to set a delay before accessing an external link.

(Click the image to trigger the animation) https://jsfiddle.net/jinzagon/e359t6fr/6/

HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://example.com" class="section"><div class="response"><img style="width:100%;"src="https://images.hdqwalls.com/wallpapers/huntdown-4k-ky.jpg"></div></a>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.section').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $a = $(this).addClass('clicked');
    setTimeout(function() {
      window.location.assign($a.attr('href'));
    }, 1700);
  });
});
```

CSS

```
a {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.section {
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
      transition: 2s ease-out;
}
.response {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 00px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: 4s ease-out;
  opacity: 1;
}
.clicked {
  animation-delay: 2s;
  animation: event 2s;
}
.clicked > .response {
  
  animation: response 4s;
}
@keyframes event {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.4);
  }
  20% {
    box-shadow: 0px 9px 14px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.6);
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.4);
  }
}
@keyframes response {
  0% {} 16% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  32% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to remove the `clicked` class. Animation is only played once because `clicked` class is only added once.

Comment: @Yousaf When you remove `clicked` the whole animation doesn't work anymore.

Comment: I meant, remove the class once the animation is complete so that when user clicks again, class is added again. You can use `animationend` event to remove the `clicked` class once the animation is complete. [Demo](https://jsbin.com/pipagosibu/1/edit?js,output)

Comment: @Yousaf Yay it's working :) What about the delay in JS ? It doesn't seem to work, whatever value I put.

Comment: Try running your code locally instead of running it in any online editor.

Comment: @Yousaf I did it locally. I published online just to share it here.

Comment: @Yousaf Can you add the script to remove the class in this script please ? I don't know how to do so https://codepen.io/jinzagon/pen/XWdVbgo